# How to maintain follow list like in Instagram?

Tags: architecture, graph, social-networking, graph-databases

I am trying to make a network similar to Instagram / Facebook principle; i.e. there will be many users and they might be connected to one another in uni-directional way. Something like a graph.

A simple and a naive approach would be to create a directory for each user and have  a JSON file listing all the other users who that user follows.

How is the performance of [Graph Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) and which one is better for a start( bascically, user friendly installation and not many .conf changes).

Please, do suggest in case there is a better design. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph database is very good for storing and traversing entities and the relationships they have to one another.  In that sense I think that looking into use of a graph database would be a good use of your time.  I would recommend starting with with TinkerPop:

http://tinkerpop.com

which offers a JDBC-like connectivity to many graph database providers.  In that way you can try out many different graph databases through a common interface to find the one that is right for your needs.  It also offers a way to get started with very little setup and configuration via Gremlin (a graph traversal language).  You can see how to get started with it here through a REPL and TinkerGraph (a simple in-memory graph):

https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Getting-Started

From there, you will want to look into different Blueprints supported graph databases (e.g. Titan, OrientDB, Neo4j to name a few) to find the right one for your needs.